# How can I add a `view` type to my identifiable data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swiftui, identifiable

I have the following data which is my identifiable. What I am trying to do is that I want to add a `type` of `view` as well so later I can give a `Button` that will link to those views. I don't know how to accomplish this. It says it doesn't accept view type.

My aim is to create cards and each card will hold `Datum` values. I want to set a `Button` to each of them that will take the user to that specific view. Since I do a `ForEach`, I want to be able to add each `Datum`'s view. I did the following but swift didn't accept it and threw error.

Here is the code:

```
struct Datum:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var subtitle:String
    var name:String
    var footnote: String
    var description:String
    var image:String
    var categoryTag:String
    var comingSoon:Bool
    //var modelName: **View**
}

public var categoriesList = ["DL", "TSA", "NLP"]

var ModelsData:[Datum] = [
    Datum(subtitle: "Deep Learning",
         name: "Mask Detection",
         footnote: "An image classificaton model.",
         description: "This model classifies whether a person has a mask        or not. You simply take your camera and then take your face. Then, it will go and scan it. After that, you will see that at the bottom it shows green (means you have a mask) or red (which means you dont have a mask.)",
         image: "MaskDetectionImage",
         categoryTag: "DL",
         comingSoon: false,
         //modelName: MaskDetectionView()),      //I want to add a view
    
    Datum(subtitle: "Deep Leaning",
         name: "Video games",
         footnote: "An image classificaton app",
         description: "This model classifies whether a person has a mask or not. You simply take your camera and then take your face. Then, it will go and scan it. After that, you will see that at the bottom it shows green (means you have a mask) or red (which means you dont have a mask.)",
         image: "latest_1",
         categoryTag: "DL",
         comingSoon: false,
         //modelName: ContentView())] //Another different view
```

Here is image:

I defined:
[image: Struct defining]

The error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Try it the other way around. Instead of making Datum's instances hold a View property; create your SwiftUI card Views to hold an instance of a Datum as a property.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Here I made an example of what you need, let me know if you need explaining.

```
import SwiftUI


struct Datum {
    var modelName: AnyView
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var datum: Datum = Datum(modelName: AnyView(Text("Omid").bold()) )
    
    
    var body: some View {

        datum.modelName
     
    }
}
```

**Here:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var ArrayOfDatum: [Datum] = ModelsData
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Divider()
        
        ForEach (0 ..< ArrayOfDatum.count) { index in
            Text(ArrayOfDatum[index].name)
            ArrayOfDatum[index].modelName
            Divider()
        }.font(Font.largeTitle.bold())
        
        
    }
}

struct Datum:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var subtitle:String
    var name:String
    var footnote: String
    var description:String
    var image:String
    var categoryTag:String
    var comingSoon:Bool
    var modelName: AnyView
}

public var categoriesList = ["DL", "TSA", "NLP"]

var ModelsData: [Datum] = [
    Datum(subtitle: "Deep Learning",
         name: "Mask Detection",
         footnote: "An image classificaton model.",
         description: "This model classifies whether a person has a mask        or not. You simply take your camera and then take your face. Then, it will go and scan it. After that, you will see that at the bottom it shows green (means you have a mask) or red (which means you dont have a mask.)",
         image: "MaskDetectionImage",
         categoryTag: "DL",
         comingSoon: false, modelName: AnyView(Image(systemName: "person")))
         //modelName: MaskDetectionView()),      //I want to add a view
    
    ,Datum(subtitle: "Deep Leaning",
         name: "Video games",
         footnote: "An image classificaton app",
         description: "This model classifies whether a person has a mask or not. You simply take your camera and then take your face. Then, it will go and scan it. After that, you will see that at the bottom it shows green (means you have a mask) or red (which means you dont have a mask.)",
         image: "latest_1",
         categoryTag: "DL",
         comingSoon: false, modelName: AnyView(Image(systemName: "gamecontroller")))
         //modelName: ContentView())] //Another different view
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added my view instead of text and got this :
`Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'modelName' conform to 'View'`

Comment: you have to add .modelName to end  try it and tell me result

Comment: 1. So I created a struct as you did.
2. Then I gave it to my identifiable -> `var modelName:Datum`
3. Then when defining each item, I added it as well. I have updated the post and added picture. Please check it out

Comment: you code it wrong! you did twice! let me see if I can edit your code.

Comment: The thing is that `fullpresentationcover` opens up a new `View` and `AnyView` != `View`

Comment: I even used a dictionary/collection by which if `key` == `id`, then give me the `View`. Still, it gave me error of `Heterogeneous` ...... and must add `[Int: Any]`

Comment: check my new code for your wrong coding way, hope help you

Answer (score 0):

This will give you some idea of how to start structuring it and how to keep the Datum model independent of SwiftUI (or however else you want to present it, save it etc).

```
struct Datum: Identifiable {
  let name: String
  var id: String { name }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var selectedDatum: Datum?
  let datums: [Datum] = [
    Datum(name: "abc"), Datum(name: "xyz")
  ]
  var body: some View {
    ForEach(datums) { datum in
      Text(datum.name)
        .onTapGesture {
          selectedDatum = datum
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedDatum) { datum in
       Color.green
        .overlay(Text(datum.name).font(.headline))
      .onTapGesture {
        selectedDatum = nil
      }
    }
  }
}
```